# How to remove trailing zeros from span element?

Tags: javascript, numbers, format

I have class number

```
<span class="sf-range-min sf-text-number">254000000</span>
<span class="sf-range-max sf-text-number">1865000000</span>
```

How to format clean `000000` 6 number 0 last of value to: `254` and `1865`.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Do you know if you want the result in a variable or if you want to change the HTML?

Comment: @CertainPerformance - thanks, I got focused on the _in class_ part.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question and include your attempt(s), thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the elements through class selector `.sf-text-number`. Then iterating over them, you can get the text inside the spans using `element.innerText`.

Now to remove the trailing zeros, you can use a regex like `(\d)0*$` - which looks for digits followed by zeros. The result of the regex match would contain the leading non-zero digits in the first matched group, which you can then access using `$1`.

```js
var numberElements = document.querySelectorAll(".sf-text-number");

for(var i = 0; i < numberElements.length; i++) {
  var elem = numberElements[i];
  console.log("The number: " + elem.innerText);
  
  elem.innerText = elem.innerText.replace(/(\d)0*$/g, "$1");
}
```

```html
<span class="sf-range-min sf-text-number">254000000</span>
<span class="sf-range-max sf-text-number">1865000000</span>
```

Comment: `innerText` is a quirky nonstandard property that IE introduced. It is highly recommended to instead use the standard, quicker, more reliable `textContent` instead - see http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText You can also iterate over the elements directly, since it's a NodeList - better abstraction, no manual iteration, when compared to a `for` loop

Comment: @CertainPerformance I doubt it is non-standard: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-innertext-idl-attribute

Comment: Exactly fomat. Thanks for support